# в websocket приходят странные байты, которые я не могу найти в rfc

Tags: c, websocket

Я писал собственную реализацию websocket и вроде бы всё было хорошо. Пока не связался с сайтов huobi.com. Когда я подписываюсь на событие, мне приходят такие байты, я смотрю только первые четыре.

```
ret: 267 total_size 0
->82 5d 1f 8b<-
ws_read: 267
ret->:-3
avail: 4096
```

потом приходят нормальные. но бывает и опять странные последовательности. вот нормальные.

```
ret: 171 total_size 0
->82 7e 00 a7<-
-->size: a7
ws_read: 167
ret->:-3
avail: 4096
```

по этим данные можно понять, что первые два байта указывают на код, следующие два байта указывают на количество байт строки.
есть ещё такие байты.

```
ret: 44 total_size 0
->82 2a 1f 8b<-
ws_read: 44
ret->:-3
avail: 4096
```

С 2a разобрался. второй байт указывает на размер, если он не больше 7e как я понял. но вот 5d я не могу понять что значит.

Comment: А какой rfc вы читаете?

Comment: @mik.ov уже не помню. да я тогда разобрался с проблемой и всё работает. уже не помню даже что было.